# How to get IR data from Wiimote? (DarwiinRemote, or WiimoteWhiteboard, etc...)

Tags: wiimote

I'm trying to get the IR data from a Wiimote via Bluetooth and am quite frustrated. I've already tried using WiimoteWhiteboard (http://www.uweschmidt.org/wiimote-whiteboard) as well as Darwiin Remote (http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwiin-remote/). Both of them display the IR data, but won't (seemingly) let me output it so that I can get to it programmatically. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I don't really care about the language necessary to do this; my group was hoping to use either Python, Java, or Processing but it's not important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interface with HID to get the Wii Remote input.  I don't know what to tell you for Python or Java, but here is the basic information on HID reports from the device:  http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#HID_Interface

I've never used it, but there is a Java class available:  http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote/Library#motej_Java_library

What I can tell you is that if you want to use .NET, there is an excellent class available over on MSDN.  Even if you don't end up using .NET, you can use this code as a good example to go off of.  http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/96133#42622

Comment: Thanks so much! Motej looks pretty cool. We ended up implementing our project for the hackathon w/o the Wiimote but I'll definitely keep this in mind for later.